How should I create/generate & persist unique identifiers from ion based stringified json?
We have a use case where we need to generate unique IDs corresponding to client provided identifiers which will be a ion string (ionified json). Once the unique IDs are generated, our system will accept & persist information on the top of that generated ID from other set of clients. There'll be other set of systems as well who will read this persisted information key-ed against the generated IDs.
Now, clients can provide us different type of identifiers, for eg. one client can send: "{external_id: \"ABC\", sequence_number:\"123\"}" , another client can send: "{internal_id:\"20\", volume_number:\"3\", sequence_id: \"GH\"}" etc. The system has a way to know what all keys can come from certain clients and in what order it is supposed to read the key-value pairs. In future, different combination may come so in those cases as well, system will have the ability to know what all keys will be coming in the ion string (ionified json).
NOTE: There'll be limit on the no of keys in such jsons (For eg. Upto 5 keys at max). The data type of each key will be simple data types like: int, string and any nested json is NOT expected. Along with the before mentioned ion string, in the request, client will also pass a param called: IdentifierType, it can have enum values like TypeA, TypeB etc. Till now, I have thought in following manner:
Option 1: Unique Id = <md5/SHA-256/some hashing algo>hash of (IdentifierType:IdentifierTypeValue#key1:keyValue1#key2:keyValue2..) where key1, key2 are keys from ion string while keyValue1, keyValue2 is the value of keys from identifiers provided by the client. For eg. in the first example above: assume IdentifierType = TypeA , client provided identifier ion string: "{external_id: \"ABC\", sequence_number:\"123\"}" , the Unique ID = <md5/SHA-256/some hashing algo>hash of (IdentifierType:TypeA#external_id:ABC#sequence_number:123), similarly, for second example, let's say IdentifierType = TypeB , the Unique ID = <md5/SHA-256/some hashing algo>hash of (IdentifierType:TypeB#internal_id:20#volume_number:3#sequence_id:GH)
Concerns: Collision concerns which would need custom solution. Also the unique IDs generated via hash may not be very readable

Custom solution: One way is to keep a mapping of concatenated ion string IdentifierType:IdentifierTypeValue#key1:keyValue1#key2:keyValue2.. and the generated hash in a database (For eg. DDB) so when some new client provided ion string comes and the generated hash is same, we can use this mapping to see if the concatenated string matches the current one sent by client or not. If it does match, then we can add salting to the hashing and re-generate the hash and use it as a unique Id. However, there's a concern that the length of the concatenated string may become too long. One way I am thinking to do is to normalize the keys to a shorter abbreviations(For eg. external_id -> extId) in the code itself before creating concatenated string but not sure how much it would help.

Option 2 (similar to Option 1): Generate UUID in application code and store mapping b/w concatenated ion string IdentifierType:IdentifierTypeValue#key1:keyValue1#key2:keyValue2.. and the UUID in database (For eg. DDB). Theoretically, UUIDs are always unique so very less chance for UUID collision. Use this generated UUID as the unique Id. However, there's a concern that the length of the concatenated string may become too long
Option 3: Just have unique Id = IdentifierType:IdentifierTypeValue#key1:keyValue1#key2:keyValue2..

Concerns: Very verbose, length issues since multiple systems are involved who interact with this unique ID so each system will need to support verbose long string based unique IDs which may not be scalable

Can folks please suggest me better ways to generate unique IDs for such client provided identifiers ? Would really appreciate best practices around the same as I may have missed some important areas so happy to correct my mistakes ? Thanks in advance!!
